# Changing the "Upload failed" Message

Tags: fine-uploader

I would like to change the "Upload failed" message to one returned from my server-side processing.

I can see the message I want in the onError callback but I'm not sure how to used that instead of the default message.

Thoughts, examples or further reading advice welcome (new here).

Comment: Are you using the default Fine Uploader UI?  Are you talking about changing the message that appears next to a failed file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of what you're trying to do depends on whether you are using Fine Uploader Basic/Core or Regular/UI. This is because UI mode offers some extra goodies for displaying error messages and such.

A few properties/options that may benefit you:

### Fine Uploader Basic/Core mode

- `text.defaultResponseError`

> Message sent to the onError callback if no specific information about the error can be determined. This is used if the server indicates failure in the response but does not include an “error” property in the response and the error code is 200 (XHR only)

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
    /* ... */
    text: {
        defaultResponseError: "Oh noes! Upload fail."
    }
});
```

[The documentation on 'text'](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/options/fineuploaderbasic.html#text-option-properties_1)

---

### Fine Uploader Regular/UI mode

- `failedUploadTextDisplay.mode` option

  > Valid values are “default” (display the text defined in failUploadText next to each failed file), “none” (don’t display any text next to a failed file), and “custom” (display error response text from the server next to the failed file or `Blob`).
- `failedUploadTextDisplay.responseProperty` option

  > The property from the server response containing the error text to display next to the failed file or `Blob`. This is ignored unless mode is “custom”.

```js
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    /* ... */
    text: {
        defaultResponseError: "Oh noes! Upload fail."
    },
    failedUploadTextDisplay: {
        mode: 'custom',              // Display error responses from the server.
        responseProperty: 'errorMsg' // Default is 'error', change this to match the 
                                     // property that contains the error message from 
                                     // your server
    }
});
```

[The documentation on `failedUploadTextDisplay`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/options/fineuploader.html#faileduploadtextdisplay-option-properties)

Comment: failedUploadTextDisplay was the option I was missing, thanks!

Comment: How change upload-status-text ?

Answer (score 0):

For people who still use FineUploaded and above does not work, that is because the key is not changed to `failUpload`.

Usage for a **custom message** on UI end would be

```
text: {
  failUpload: 'Your upload faile message goes here
},
```

More details can be found here - https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/upgrading-to-4.html

If you want to **display the server-side message**, you can do it the below way:

```
failedUploadTextDisplay {
  mode: 'custom',
  responseProperty: 'server side error key goes here'
}
```

If you wish to **completely remove** it, i.e, not show the message below file if file upload has failed, use below

```
failedUploadTextDisplay {
  mode: 'none'
}
```